# Number of converter instance for binding in UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

How many instance does binding creates internally for converters.

```
<Image x:Uid="DisplayedImageUrl" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" 
      Source="{Binding DisplayedImageURL, Converter={StaticResource ImageLogoConverter}}" />
```

How many instance does of ImageLogoConverter will be there?

Is it good idea to use converter in ViewModel, if not then what is the best way to access converted value of ViewModel property.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good idea to use converter in ViewModel?

No. Why would you use a converter in a view model where you can return the converted value directly? Converters are used in the view, typically to convert a non-view friendly value that the view model returns.

> If not then what is the best way to access converted value of ViewModel property?

You can simpy return an already converted value from the view model, i.e. instead of binding to a `Uri` property, you may bind directly to an `ImageSource` property.

This is the recommnded approach if you for example intend to display a lot of elements in a `ItemsControl`. Then you probably don't want to invoke a converter for each visible element for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you created the converter as a resource like this:

The number of instances now depends on the scope where the converter resource is declared. If you create it in `<Page.Resources>`, one instance will be created to be used by the page. If you create it in `App.xaml` in `<Application.Resources>` it will be an application-wide instance. Of course, you can even use a narrower scope - create it as a resource of a single control in your XAML tree for example - in any case, a single instance is created when instance of the parent is created.

The situation gets a bit more interesting if you embed it in a `ItemTemplate` of a list control. Thanks to virtualization, the system will not actually create one instance for each item. Instead, it will create only so many instances as fit on the screen and they get reused when the user scrolls.

Some MVVM developers don't like value converters, but others use them extensively. It really is a matter of preference. In cas you expect the underlying data to change often, it is advisable to keep the code in the converter as performant as possible as it runs on the UI thread.